# Mod_Rewrite RewriteRule issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a domain at example.com

There is a subdirectory that has a quiz on it, located at example.com/quiz/?id=1

I need to change the ?id=1 to TakeTheQuiz so it would look like example.com/quiz/TakeTheQuiz

Here is what my .htaccess looks like right now (the .htaccess is located in the root direct at example.com). Right now I always get a server 500 error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /quiz
RewriteRule ^?id=1$ TaketheQuiz
```

This is really simple and all of the examples I have seen have been really complicated and hard for me to apply it to this one :( Help, anyone? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You've just got the rule the wrong way round:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /quiz
RewriteRule ^TaketheQuiz$ ?id=1 [L]
```

**EDIT**

Per your comment try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=1
RewriteRule ^$ TaketheQuiz [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I did exactly what you said, but it's still not working. I'm not getting the 500 server error anymore, but the page isn't rewriting to TaketheQuiz, it's just staying at example.com/?id=1

Comment: Hm, it's the same thing as before; no 500 server error, but no rewriting either.